# Multi idiomas em Laravel 5

Tags: laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um projecto no laravel 5, mas gostaria que o mesmo fosse em varios idiomas. A mudanca do idioma seria ao clicar no link de cada idioma e automaticamente ele traduzia o site naquele idioma. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traduzir automaticamente nunca será perfeito, e o php ou laravel não são "bases de dados" de multilinguagens que interpretam textos em diferentes idiomas, eles são linguagem de programação e framework respectivamente que rodam no **back-end**, quem tem que criar a tradução é você, usando a programação.

No entanto é possivel fazer uma tradução automática com Javascript e Google-translate (que é **front-end**), mas é como eu já disse *"não vai ficar perfeito"* veja um exemplo nesta resposta:

- [Como customizar o google-translate no meu site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82760/3635)

No entanto se você quer programar, o Laravel (exemplos pro 5.2) tem o Localization que é uma maneira de projetar sites multi-idiomas, a estrutura de pastas:

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            messages.php
        /pt
            messages.php
```

en/messages.php

```
<?php    
return [
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to our application'
];
```

pt/messages.php

```
<?php    
return [
    'welcome' => 'Bem vindo a sua aplicação'
];
```

Um exemplo de Rota:

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
});
```

Isso não vai traduzir as informações que veem do banco de dados, mas sim o conteúdo do layout e se tiver uma série de textos padrões no banco será possivel traduzi-los desde que siga uma padrão unico.

Documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization

Comment: Muito obrigado cara. A sua resposta ajudou e tanto. Estou usando mesmo o recurso do Laravel "localization" e achei muito bacana. Brigadão.