# Como traduzir textos dinâmicos com php?

Tags: php, tradução

Bom Galera estou querendo traduzir um texto com php porem não consigo achar um api funcional.
Tentei fazer isso funcionar da seguinte maneira

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="#" >
       <textarea name="texto"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="Traduzir"/>
    </form>

    <?php
    $texto       = $_POST['texto'];
    $language    = "pt_BR";
    $language_for= "en";
    if($texto != NULL){

    //aqui a tradução

    }else{
    echo "Sem Texto Para Traduzir";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Como posso fazer isso funcionar?
PS: Necessito que esse texto seja traduzido com ajuda de algum api devido ao texto ser pego aleatoriamente em outro site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar https://github.com/Stichoza/google-translate-php, que usa o Google Tradutor:

Instale via [**composer**](https://getcomposer.org) na pasta do teu projeto:

```
composer require stichoza/google-translate-php
```

O uso é algo como:

```
use Stichoza\GoogleTranslate\TranslateClient;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$tr = new TranslateClient('en', 'pt'); //Inglês para português

echo $tr->translate('Hello World!'), PHP_EOL;

echo $tr->translate('Good morning!'), PHP_EOL;
```

---

Outro projeto que encontrei https://github.com/statickidz/php-google-translate-free

Pra instalar execute o comando na pasta do teu projeto:

```
composer require statickidz/php-google-translate-free
```

O uso deve ser algo como:

```
use Statickidz\GoogleTranslate;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$tr = new GoogleTranslate();

echo $tr->translate('en', 'pt', 'Hello World!'), PHP_EOL;

echo $tr->translate('en', 'pt', 'Good morning!'), PHP_EOL;
```

---

### Extras/relacionados

Existem algumas perguntas no site que podem ser interessante, não falam de tradução de texto por API, mas sim da criação de sites multilinguagem:

- [Como traduzir um site em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15937/3635)
- [Site em dois idiomas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110553/3635)
- [Adicionando linguagem manualmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152370/3635)
- [Como tornar um site multilíngue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21788/3635)

Outra pergunta, para quem quer traduzir o seu site rapidamente, sem paginação ou apenas facilitar o processo de tradução é com a ferramenta do Google Tradutor

- [Como customizar o google-translate no meu site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82739/3635)

Claro que essa ferramenta do Google não é 100%, mas funciona bem no geral.

Comment: Usarei um host, será possível fazer a instalação do mesmo no host?

Comment: @CarlosdaSilva baixa o projeto do host pra sua maquina, instala o composer na sua máquina, instala com o comando que mandei, adiciona o autoload.php ajusta os códigos como no exemplo e envia novamente pro teu HOST via FTP.

Comment: Ah ta consegui compreender o composer é uma ferramenta que auxilia na instalação do pacote vindo do github

Comment: @CarlosdaSilva é sim, como indiquei no https://getcomposer.org/, recomendo que **antes de mudar qualquer coisa no teu projeto** estudo muito bem o composer, hoje é raro quem não usa composer em projetos mais sérios, somente alguns não usam composer, quem não sabe o que é quando o projeto é bem simples. Só pra constar, composer não é algo que se aprende da noite para o dia, a não ser que você já tenha tido experiencia com PIP, NPM ou ferramentas semelhantes, então se não entende composer ainda recomendo ler com muita calma e atenção e faça backup do teu projeto.

Comment: Já usei NPM, estou voltando aqui apenas para informar que consegui oque desejava. Agradeço ao mesmo